# How to test the rules of undefined behavior in respect to sequence point?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I am reading about UB from 2 days and a confusion is growing in my mind about the following example

```
int a=5;
a++ & printf("%d",a);//i know that `&` introduced here is not a sequence point.
```

Now,it is UB in c but i am looking at it from a different angel as following

now c standard says

`Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.`

So,as we are modifying the value of a by writing `a++` only once,this rule fails in declaring the behavior as UB.
But further it states that

`Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.`

As the prior value of `a` ( 5 here ) is accessed via `a++` to write the value of `a` .But in the statement `printf("%d",a)`

`("%d",a)` is a full expression.so `all the dust of side effect should be settled down` before the expression runs.
As according to standard

`when a function call is made there is sequence point before the actual call and after the evaluation of arguments.`

so `a` should have been modified here in the function call,more precise to say that value of `a` is updated according to the standard.
Then why it is yet UB as `("%d",a)` is an expression in itself and it is evaluated before `;`?

Comment: **Static analyzers**. You can never test anything about Undefined Behaviour, because, well, it's Undefined! (when you're implementing the compiler you can test some parts, _as long_ as it is Implementation Defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `a++ & printf("%d",a)` contains five interesting steps:

- A) read a
- B) increment a
- C) read a
- D) call printf
- E) bitwise-and

You may expect C++ to execute these steps from top to bottom (A->B->C->D->E), because humans tend to read from left to right. But in fact, C++ only gives you the following guarantees:

- A is executed before B (A->B)
- C is executed before D (C->D), because functions need to know their arguments
- A and D are executed before E (A->E, D->E), because operators need to know their operands
- If A is executed before D (A->D), then B is also executed before D (B->D), because `a++` has a side effect, function calls are sequence points, and side effects are guaranteed to be visible by then.

Note that there is no guarantee of the form (A->C) or (B->C). This is what most beginners don't get.

Does C read the value before or after the increment that happens at B? We do not know!

- The operator `&` does not impose any restrictions on the order of evaluation of its operands, so the second operand `printf("%d",a)` may be evaluated before the first operand `a++`. (The evaluations of the operands may also be interleaved, as long as they obey the above guarantees.)
- Even *if* the first operand is evaluated before the second operand, the side effect that happens in B is not guaranteed to be visible when C is executed. (It *would* be visible at D then, because function calls are sequence points, but by then it's too late. The arguments have already been evaluated.)

These restrictions leave us with the following possible execution orders:

- A->B->C->D->E
- A->C->B->D->E
- C->A->B->D->E
- C->D->A->B->E
- C->A->B->D->E

It took me several attempts to write this list down. I am not 100% certain it is correct and complete.

Comment: thanxxx a lot for clarifying me

Comment: but as you said that "Even if the first operand is evaluated before the second operand, the side effect that happens in B is not guaranteed to be visible when C is executed. (It would be visible at D then, because function calls are sequence points, but by then it's too late. The arguments have already been evaluated.)"i am confused here because you said it is visible at D so why the previous value of a is passed and not the incremented?is it also possible this way as this is UB?

Comment: Step C determines which value is passed, and step D calls the function with the value determined at step C. If B happens between C and D, the old value is passed. I don't see how I can make it any clearer than that.

Comment: sorry if i am testing your patience but in your sequence you write A->C->B->D->E both A and C follows same operation of reading A but compiler can perform optimization for this also.secondly if B happens between C and D,every time it is not necessary that the value is passed ( as you commented "is passed" which i feel is not the correct word) is the old one.As it is UB new    value may also get passed.please clarify if i have any misconception.

Comment: What exactly do you think "passed" means? Arguments are *passed* to functions. In your example, `"%d"` and `a` are passed to `printf`. You have probably heard of the terms "pass by value" and "pass by reference". Those are different ways to pass arguments to functions. Maybe your are confusing "passed" with "skipped" or something? I can't think of other interpretations right now.

Answer (score 2):

`("%d",a)` is not a full-expression. In this context, it is not even an expression. It is the list of arguments to a function. The full-expression in your code is everything on your second line, except for the `;`.

> A full expression is an expression that is not part of another expression or of a declarator.

The access of `a` within the argument list does not have an intervening sequence-point between it and the `a++`, and it is not for the purpose of doing `a++`, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: is it so that in my expression i am reading `a` and writing to it in the same expression.so it is undefined.

Comment: @Bayant_singh yes, correct. It is undefined behaviour precisely because of the second point you have listed. The function call `printf("%d", a)` accesses the value of `a` and this has nothing to do with the computation of the new value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`So,as we are modifying the value of a by writing`a++`only once,this rule fails in declaring the behavior as UB.`

Here `a++ & printf("%d",a);` - the only sequence points are `;` and before `printf` is entered when invoked.

You can clearly see `a` is being modified and being read from at the same time within a single sequence point `;`. Hence re-stating with emphasis:

A sequence point is a point in time at which the dust has settled and all side effects which have been seen so far are guaranteed to be complete. The sequence points listed in the C standard are:

> at the end of the evaluation of a full expression (a full
>   expression is an expression statement, or any other expression which
>   is not a subexpression within any larger expression);
>       at the ||, &&, ?:, and comma operators; and
>       at a function call (after the evaluation of all the arguments, and just before the actual call).

The Standard states that

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object **shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once** by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

Comment: but `("%d",a)` is also a full expression.so what effect it will make?

Comment: @Bayant_singh - even `"%d"` is a full expression, even `a` is a full expression. So what about that?

Comment: but these are not full to be precise these are the sub-expressions of the ("%d",a).

Answer (score 1):

What you are confusing is about what side effects are. Both `printf("%d",a)` and `a++` have side effect, according to:

> #### C11 5.1.2.3 Program execution
>
> Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function
>   that does any of those operations are all side effects,12) which are changes in the state of
>   the execution environment.

`printf("%d",a)` is modifying the state of the execution environment. A function that has no side effect is a function that does nothing except return a value that is determined only by its arguments.